# Modifying UHD code to work with GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, probe, uhd

I need to modify the UHD code and then need to make that code work with gnuradio-companion. For this, I built UHD from source and made the required modifications.

The next step would have been to build GNU Radio by source. But the installation steps mentioned in the [tutorial](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/InstallingGR#From_Source) do not seem to take UHD into account here. Also, the change in UHD is not being detected in an already installed version of GNU radio.

How do I make GNU Radio work with the modified UHD code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to uninstall your currently installed GNU Radio, your currently installed UHD (make **doubly** sure you've removed both), then you need to install your self-built UHD, then build and install GNU Radio. Make sure not to accidentally install your operating system's UHD again!

You *cannot* make a GNU Radio that was built with a different version
of UHD work with your version; you need to built it.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.